# Carat not rotating on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a rotate function for the `carat` from a bootstrap `dropup`. The problem is it doesn't transition (rotate) when I close the `dropup`. Here is the link to my codepen. http://codepen.io/theMugician/pen/OyjYed
***The dropup is not closing and opening in the codepen. Just pay attention to the carat***

```
<div class="dropup" id="divDropup">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu text-left" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <li>PHONE</li>Stuff<li>{{basket.plan.phonePrice}}</li>
        <li>MONTHLY PLAN</li><li>{{basket.plan.planPrice}}</li>
        <li>ACCESSORIES</li><li>{{basket.accessoriesTotal}}</li>
        <li>BUNDLE</li><li>{{basket.bundle.price}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<footer id="cartFooter">
    <div class="row cartInfo">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p><i class="zmdi zmdi-shopping-cart"></i> CART</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
            <p>{{basket.total}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
            <p><a ng-click="emptyBasket()"><span class="zmdi zmdi-delete"></span></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
    .rotate {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: .3s;
}
.rotate2 {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    transition: .3s;
}
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  var $rotate = function(){
                    $("#divDropup").on("click",function(){
                        $(".caret").toggleClass("rotate");
                        $(".caret").toggleClass("rotate2");
                    })
                }
                $rotate();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the Class 'rotate' up front so when you toggle the class it removes it when adding the other. You're adding both classes on click then removing both classes on the second click.

```
<span class="caret rotate"></span>
```